# Is it insecure for the user to know the process id of a background script on my web server?

Tags: linux, php, javascript, ajax

I was experiencing an issue on one of my webpages, where an AJAX call is made to another script on the server to generate some files for download. Depending on things like server load, number of files needed, etc., the call was timing out.

I took the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7637312/5898423), and adjusted the code to make an initial AJAX call to start the script in the background, and then multiple repeated AJAX calls to query the status of it. When the initial AJAX call is made, the *process id* of the script is returned to the client, which is then used by the subsequent calls to check whether the script is still running.

Does the fact that the client knows the actual pid of a process running on the server create any sort of security vulnerability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pid has limited utility to derive information about the host's system state. Eg. low pid would indicate recent reboot, high pid a long running system (depending on the load and services). Attacker could constantly monitor your actual pid and make educated guess about uptime. Eg. predict if an important kernel security patch was applied or not.

If the polling ajax call request isn't verified (eg. using HMAC) the attacker could scan the running process ids by forging the pid and repeating the call. That way the attacker could identify the long running processes (webserver, database pids).

None of them seem to be very serious security problem to me, but it's better safe than sorry. You can easily encrypt the pid with a local secret if you like.

Comment: Thanks for those examples. You were correct in your guess in a below comment about me trying to make this stateless. Probably best to simply add a database with a job id,  randomised secret and encrypted pid, and only return the job id to the client?

Comment: A randomized token would be just enough. This is how most sessions work. You don't need secrets, no information can be derived from a rnd token. (Actually there is more info in the job-id because it's sequential). Storing a tokens in db and submitting for later reference is relatively cheap since you seemingly don't want to return any results (just the fact the process is finished).

Answer (score 0):

I think using a pid for this is probably inappropriate.   It doesn't guarantees what you are checking (because pids can wrap), and it may leak information, and it provides a path for the remote to forge pids and scan what pids are on your system.

It would be better to generate a handle (session cookie?) and keep track of the background script in the server side session information.

Comment: Sure. There are several methods. Probably pid based method is an attempt to make the system stateless (no database or session needed). In reality the solution only delegates state to the process management which is suboptimal. Anyways, the question was about pid security not the actual solution.